# How to add values in session and list in html table?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having sample html table

```
<table border="1" id="tableid">
            <tr>
                <th><a href="javascript:edit();" class="editclass">E</a> <a href="javascript:deleteClass();">D</a> <a href="javascript:viewClass();" class="viewClass">V</a> <a href="javascript:addClass();" class="addClass">A</a><br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
                <th>Cell phone</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case"
                    name="case" value="1" /></td>
                <td class="cellclass">BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
                <td>2/5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case"
                    name="case" value="2" /></td>
                <td class="cellclass">Samsung Galaxy</td>
                <td>3.5/5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case"
                    name="case" value="3" /></td>
                <td class="cellclass">Droid X</td>
                <td>4.5/5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case"
                    name="case" value="4" /></td>
                <td class="cellclass">HTC Desire</td>
                <td>3/5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case"
                    name="case" value="5" /></td>
                <td class="cellclass">Apple iPhone 4</td>
                <td>5/5</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

<div id="editId" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
            <p id="editHeadId"></p>
            Cell Name: <input type="text" name="cellname" id="txtCell"/><br/>
            Rating: <input type="text" name="rating" id="txtRating"/><br/>
            <button class="submitclass">Submit</button> <button class="updateclass">Update</button> <button class="cancelclass">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

I want to store a list of objects in session only maintaining in html page, but i am not using any servlet or action class. I want to store some more objects in the session and show in the table by using create page with two fields. That too i can had values to the table by using jquery

```
$(".submitclass").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var rowCount = $('#tableid tr:last').index() + 1;
        $("#tableid tr").last().after(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\" name=\"case\" value="+ rowCount + " /></td>"+
                "<td>"+$("[name='cellname']").val()+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+$("[name='rating']").val()+"</td>"+
                "</tr>");
        $("[name='cellname']").val("");
        $("[name='rating']").val("");

    });
```

But the thing is when the page is refreshed the last entered datas are deleted only the values present static is present. For dynamic i can use array object and use in session, but i don't know which is the easiest way to approach using jquery.

Comment: where is the .submitclass?

Comment: i've edited the content for .submitclass

Comment: might want to look into knockout rather than jQuery, jQuery is ok for simple DOM manipulation, but when you're talking a model iterated in a table and performing actions against it it is easier to have knockout hook everything up

Comment: I don’t see anything that could be considered a “session” in the code shown.

Comment: @Manoj I have edited my post, check.

Answer (score 0):

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    return null;
 }


$("document").ready(function(){

var cookiecellnames=[];
var cookieratings=[];

var readcellnames=readCookie("cellnames");
var ratingsValues=readCookie("ratings");


if(readcellnames && ratingsValues){
    var cellnamesValue=readcellnames.split(",");
    var arrayLength = cellnamesValue.length;

    var ratingsValue=ratingsValues.split(",");

        for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            cookiecellnames.push(cellnamesValue[i]);
            cookieratings.push(ratingsValue[i]);
            $("#tableid tr").last().after(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\" name=\"case\" value="+arrayLength+" /></td>"+
                "<td>"+cellnamesValue[i]+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+ratingsValue[i]+"</td>"+
                "</tr>");
        }
}
//alert(cellnamesValue);


    $(".submitclass").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var rowCount = $('#tableid tr:last').index() + 1;
        $("#tableid tr").last().after(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\" name=\"case\" value="+ rowCount + " /></td>"+
                "<td>"+$("[name='cellnames']").val()+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+$("[name='ratings']").val()+"</td>"+
                "</tr>");

        cookiecellnames.push($("[name='cellnames']").val());
        document.cookie = "cellnames="+cookiecellnames;

        cookieratings.push($("[name='ratings']").val());
        document.cookie = "ratings="+cookieratings;

        $("[name='cellnames']").val("");
        $("[name='ratings']").val("");

    });
});
```